# Doubly Linked List using 3 arrays

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Let L be a doubly linked list of length m stored in arrays key, prev, and next, which are all of length n. Suppose that these arrays are managed by ALLOCATE_OBJECT and FREE_OBJECT procedures that keep a doubly linked free list F. Suppose further that of the n items [which can be described by the three arrays, exactly m are on list L, and the other n-m are on the free-list F. Write a procedure COMPACTIFY_LIST(L,F) that moves the items in L so that they occupy array positions 1,2,...,m and adjusts the index values in all the arrays so that the L lists remains in the same order, and the F list contains the nsame number of elements as before, now occupying positions m+1, m+1, .., n in the arrays.

I can only think of an O(n) program where I keep two pointers. I start with both pointers at the beginning of the array key. Pointer1 looks for the first available empty space , and the pointer2 then looks for the first index of the array after this position which contains an element of the linked list. Then move this element to the position which pointer1 is pointing at, and then pointer1 looks for the next empty space and continue. But this procedure will take O(n) time, if i am not wrong. I cannot think of an O(m) algorithm.

P.S. Yes, this is homework. But I am stuck and some help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sufficient to place each element [i] of L in position [i] of the base arrays A. Read through L and trade each element found with whatever element already occupies its assigned position in the A. This clearly has O(m) complexity.

Comment: What do you mean by placing each element[i] of L in position[i] of the base arrays? Thank you so much for replying but I am not able to understand your solution. Can you please elaborate this a little?

Comment: What is there not to understand? Please be more specific with what is giving you difficulty.

Comment: @tanvi: Both; that is the trick. Element [i] of L is mapped directly to element [i] of A, by being traded with whatever element of L or F is already  there.

Comment: Ok, so I will be using two pointers, one starting from L, and one from the array. And if the value at key[pointer] do not match, I swap?